# How to define new models in Tensorflow Object Detection API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

Tensorflow Object Detection API is a marvelous resource and a unique piece of well-documented code. Its performance on object detection encourage me to use this API for detecting object poses similar to [Poirson et. al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.05590.pdf)

In the case of faster-rcnn meta-architecture, pose detection requires adding a new regression layer along with bbox classification & regression layers and modifying ground truth feeding pipeline.

So, is there an easy way to modify the networks? Or should I dig into the code and make proper modifications which seems challenging? Any sample work or guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find anything on this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. API is well written but modifying it is very hard and time consuming. So I find a new repo that implements retina-net in keras [https://github.com/delftrobotics/keras-retinanet]. So it is way more easy to modify.

Comment: Thanks alot. I really appreciate the feedback

Comment: You're welcome. If you find anything, please share with me.

Comment: Sure thing ;-) .